# Intersection of a Subgroup with an Abelian Subgroup is Normal in the Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

**Question:** Let $A$ be an Abelian group with $A \trianglelefteq G$, and let $B \leq G$ be any subgroup. Show that $A \cap B \trianglelefteq AB$.

[ref: this is exercise 20 on page 96 of [DF] := Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, $3^{\text{rd}}$ edition]

**My attempt:** Clearly, $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ (because $B \leq G = N_G (A)$, so this is just corollary 15 on page 94 of [DF]). As $A \cap B$ is also a subgroup, we therefore already have $A \cap B \leq AB$, so we only need to show that $AB$ normalises $A \cap B$.

Let $ab \in AB$. What is $(ab) A\cap B (ab)^{-1}$? Choosing any $g \in A \cap B$, we note that in particular $g \in A$, so
$$
ab gb^{-1} a^{-1} = aa'a^{-1} = a' \in A,
$$
since $A$ is Abelian.

**Now, I'm stuck:** I would like to show that the same $ab gb^{-1} a^{-1}$ also lies in $B$ by taking into account that $g \in B$. This will then show that $(ab) A\cap B (ab)^{-1} \subset A \cap B$, and we are done.

Comment: You have taken effort to post your question, even though this is your first post. Keep your good work going and hope we'll see you more often

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $AB$ normalizes $A\cap B$ it suffices to show that $A$ and $B$ separately normalize $A\cap B$ (because this will imply that $\langle A,B\rangle\subseteq N_G(A\cap B)$, and the product is the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$).

If $x\in A\cap B$, and $b\in B$, then $bxb^{-1}\in A$ (since $x\in A\triangleleft G$), and $bxb^{-1}\in B$ (since $b,x\in B$), so $bxb^{-1}\in A\cap B$.  So $B$ normalizes $A\cap B$.

If $x\in A\cap B$ and $a\in A$, then $axa^{-1}=x\in A\cap B$, because $x\in A$ and $A$ is abelian. So $A$ normalizes $A\cap B$.

Therefore, $AB=\langle A,B\rangle \subseteq N_G(A\cap B)$, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

$bgb^{-1}=b'$ is an element of $A\cap B$ (if $g\in A$ it is normalized as you said, and if $g\in B$ we have a product in the subgroup $B$) and $ab'a^{-1}=b'\in A\cap B$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $bgb^{-1} \in A$ as $A \lhd G$, and $bgb^{-1} \in B$, because $B$ is a subgroup. Thus $bgb^{-1} \in A \cap B$. Now, $A$ is abelian, so $a(bgb^{-1})a^{-1} = aa^{-1}(bgb^{-1}) = bgb^{-1} \in A \cap B$. We conclude that $A \cap B \lhd AB$.